Why is $\int_a^x f'(x) dx$ a valid operation?
Origin of the question
My calculus class was given the following question
$$\text{Let } \ f'(x)=\frac{192x^3}{2+\sin^3(πx)} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\quad\text{and}\quad f(0.5)=0.\\\text{If} \  m≤\int^1_\frac 12 f(x) dx ≤M, \text{find} \ m,M.$$
My teacher gave us a hint of using $\int_\frac 12 ^x f'(x) dx$.
My question
Where my main concern lies is that according to this post and my own (very minuscule) knowledge, $\int_a^x f(x) dx$ is very ambiguous, and is basically meaningless. But then, $f'(x)=g(x)$ so we are cycling back to $\int_a^x g(x) dx$.  How can it be used then?

As explained in the post you link, $\int_a^xf(x)dx$ is a notation mistake. What is meant is $\int_a^xf(s)ds$.

I am voting to close as a duplicate of the linked post Why is $\int_0^x f(x) dx$ wrong?, where a detailed answer was already given.

Better ask your teacher to be more respectful to you and fix their notations. Additionaly, some $ds$ are missing in their two integrals. Moreover, their question itself is carelessly written. $m,M$ are not unique.

sometimes it's just laziness, I wouldn't think twice but really in a first course they ought to be more careful. or write $\int_a^x f$ if they don't want to introduce another variable

@AnneBauval oops forgot to give f(1/2)

Once that notation problem is fixed, hint: $-1\le\sin(\pi s)\le1$ (or even $0\le\sin(\pi s)\le1$ if $\frac12\le s\le1$), and $\int_{1/2}^xt^3dt$ is easy.
